# new Gson().toJson(object) return null for singleton class

Tags: java, singleton, gson

**My Requirement:**   I want to convert singleton object to string and again string to object.

so, i use Gson to convert object to string using toJson() method and string to object using fromJson().

I have two class:
Person class that is singleton class.

```
public class Person {

     public String Name= "rich";
     public String Address="U.K";
     public static Person person = null;

     private Person()
     {

     }
     public static Person getInstance()
     {
         if(person == null)
             return new Person();
         else 
             return person;
     }
}
```

second one: GsonConvertor class

```
public class GsonConvertor {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Person person = Person.getInstance();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonPerson = gson.toJson(person);

        System.out.println("String of Person Object: " + jsonPerson);

        Person per = gson.fromJson(jsonPerson, Person.class);
        System.out.println("Object from String" + per.toString());
    }

}
```

`gson.toJson(person);` return null.

Can anyone give me suggestion where did i mistake.I want object from `Gson.fromJson()` that i create when i call `getInstance()` method of Person class.

Comment: Using a singleton does not make much sense, If you are using rest. It will work with just ONE connection.

Comment: I use this concept in Storm. So, when i create topology that time i create a object and that object pass to all the bolt and spout. That why i convert that Object to string and pass to Config class. In the Spout class we convert that string to Object and pass to all bolt class.

Comment: But if it is a singleton the next time you want to convert from json to object, which instance do you  create?

Comment: Person class only. Person per = gson.fromJson(String of Person class, Person.class);

Comment: Btw, it's not a singleton, the field person into Person.java is never assigned and it's always null value. So each time you call getInstance() you create a new one instance

Comment: If I am not mistaken singleton is one instance of a class. The time you want to add a second person the pattern will preclude you from creating another person. Good luck